# Lowercase strings and replace spaces with dashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have the following array:

```
["Main", "Category 1", "Category2", "Category 3"]
```

Is there a way to make a copy of this array, but make all of the strings lowercase and replace the spaces with a dash ("-")?

I know I can do this for the replacing of spaces, but I do not know how to iterate over the array.

```
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"-"];
```

My end goal is to have an array that looks like this:

```
["main", "category-1", "category2", "category-3"]
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: @originaluser2 I'm using Objective-C. I was just typing an array so you could see what I'm working with.

Comment: yea, I figured as much just after I wrote the comment :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to loop through the array and call `lowercaseString` to make the string lower, and then for replacing spaces, I split the string into components using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` then combine the component with `componentsJoinedByString:`

For example:

```
NSString *string = @"Company 1";

NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];

string = [[[string lowercaseString]
            componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant]
            componentsJoinedByString: @"-"];
```

EDIT:

Assuming the array is of `NSMutableArray`, you can call `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject` (otherwise you would have to copy each index into a new array)

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[[array[i] lowercaseString] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @"-"]];
}
```

Comment: How would I loop through the array? That's the part I'm unsure of.